.htaccess 301 redirect & general RewriteRule to remove .php extensions
I'm not familiar with htaccess and RegEx.
I want to have a general htaccess rule that removes .php extensions.
And additionally do a 301 redirects.
Below is more detail and examples:
There are php files in the root directory of my website that I want to move to a sub-folder and I'm creating those sub-folders.
For example, I want to move: /about-us.php and customer-service.php, etc..
To: /company/about-us.php, /customer-service/contact-customer-service.php, example result:
https://example.com/about-us
to:
https://example.com/company/about-us
I have created those sub-folders and have moved those files and have created the links internally, but I wanted to do 301 redirects for all of those files so Google's index gets updated.
I found below rules that removes the PHP extensions (this is for internal redirecting of .php to the .php page without the extension), both code seems to work, but I do not understand the difference, any help on which code I should use is greatly appreciated:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

I used below rule which seems to work to do the 301 redirect for Google indexing purposes.
RewriteRule ^about-us.php$ https://example.com/company/about-us [R=301,NC,L]
Initially, I struggled with the above rule because I was using RewriteRule ^about-us$ instead of RewriteRule ^about-us.php$ and now it is working.
So, my only dilemma is understanding the difference between below rules for removing the .php extensions in the URLs and if I'm doing these RewriteRule correctly for my purpose:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]


Can you clarify where the .php file(s) are that actually handle the request? Are they in the root, as your rule appears to suggest? Is /company a physical filesystem directory? Or is that just in the URL? What URL(s) are you linking to internally?

Thank you, I updated with more clarity, I was able to get things working, but not sure if I'm doing things correctly because I'm not as familiar with htaccess rules
